# Deep convolutional neural net architecture gives error in the end. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I built a deep convolutional neural network, but I messed up somewhere. My output dimensions are just a little off, and I can't figure out why.

```
encoding_dim = 512   
input_image = Input(shape=train_images.shape[1:]) # (214, 214, 3)

# Build model
autoencoder = Sequential()
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(2*encoding_dim, (12, 12), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape,
                           kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
autoencoder.add(BatchNormalization())
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(encoding_dim, (12, 12), padding='same', activation='relu',
                           kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
autoencoder.add(BatchNormalization())
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(encoding_dim, (12, 12), padding='same', activation='relu',
                           kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
autoencoder.add(BatchNormalization())
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(2*encoding_dim, (12, 12), padding='same', activation='relu',
                           kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
autoencoder.add(BatchNormalization())
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(3, (12, 12), padding='same', activation='sigmoid',
                           kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
autoencoder.add(BatchNormalization())

# Compile
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected batch_normalization_5 to have shape (216, 216, 3) but got array with shape (214, 214, 3)
```

Comment: Have you used `autoencoder.summary()` to print your model and look at the dimensions? Being off by such a small amount makes me think that there's a problem with padding somewhere.

Comment: Good idea! Looks like an extra pixel gets added with each UpSampling2D layer. Strange, is it due to the way I'm building my model, you think? I made some before, but I used the "x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)" notation.

Comment: The notation shouldn't make a difference (I think). Is this a model that you've created, or is it a published model that you can check your dimensions against?

Comment: It's an adaptation of stuff I found along the way, I suppose. Pretty basic CNN, just fiddled with the dimensions. No immediate publication to look for.

Comment: It sounds like you'll sort it out by playing about with the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out. I chose my image dimensions poorly, basically. Image dimensions were 214 x 214 x 3, causing my downsampling (the MaxPooling2D layers) to have to round the dimensions (214 -> 107 -> 54). UpSampling didn't have that problem, so it didn't add up towards the end.

Answer (score 0):

This happens usually when you downsample with MaxPooling and you reach a layer where height and width are not an even number (take the simple case of H=W and even).